# c++ template function overload for pointer type

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I am using `std::type_index` objects as unique identifiers for state classes (basically, keys in a factory function to produce new objects of the referenced type).  The ID for a class, an object of that class, and a pointer to an object of that class should all be the same.  Hence, I tried to do:

```
using stateid_t = std::type_index;
template<class T> inline stateid_t GetStateID() { return typeid(T); }
template<class T> inline stateid_t GetStateID(const T&) { return typeid(T); }
template<class T> inline stateid_t GetStateID(const T*) { return typeid(T); }
```

However, the third version never gets called with something like `GetStateID(this);`, always the second version, with the type of T deduced as "pointer to T".

I *think* I ought to be able to do this somehow using `std::enable_if`, but I can't seem to come up with anything that works.

## Edit

The main thing I want is a set of functions that satisfies

```
struct A{};
A a;
const A b;
//fixed asserts based on comments
assert(GetStateID<A>() == GetStateID(a));
assert(GetStateID(a) == GetStateID(&a));
assert(GetStateID(a) == GetStateID(b));

//added some new constraints
struct X : public A{};
X x;
assert(GetStateID<A>() != GetStateID<X>());
assert(GetStateID(a) != GetStateID(x));
```

Bonus points for an explanation of why the pointer overload is not being selected.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I get `'remove_reference_t' is not a member of 'std'` and same for `remove_pointer_t`.  Presumably you mean `remove_reference::type` unless this is something compiler-specific.  Either way, why not make a proper answer so other idiots like me can find it in the future?

Comment: The `[trait]_t` helper alias were added in c++14. Perhaps you are not compiling with c++14 support. In that case using `typename` and `::type` will do the same thing.

Comment: The proper answer would depend on what you want to do - figure out why your overload is not called, or derive type_index in a most efficient way?

Comment: @thegreatemu I've formed an answer from my previous comments.

Comment: ...and the first comparison compares the function itself with the other functions return value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you are calling these functions from a non-`const` member functions. If that's the case then `stateid_t GetStateID(const T*)` requires an implicit conversion (from `U*` to `const U*` where `U` is the class' type) whereas `stateid_t GetStateID(const T&)` does not (`U` would be `U*`). In the context of a `const` member function your `this` pointer would already be a `const U *` which doesn't require an implicit conversion and should call `stateid_t GetStateID(const T*)`.

Removing those `const` should fix the problem. Both `U*` and `const U*` would prefer `stateid_t GetStateID(T*)` over `stateid_t GetStateID(T&)`.

However, it seems you may be trying to implement a solution to a solved problem. The expression `typeid(std::remove_pointer_t<T>);` should produce what you want already. In terms of your code, the following should work for you :

```
using stateid_t = std::type_index;
template<class T> inline stateid_t GetStateID() { 
    return typeid(std::remove_pointer_t<T>);
}
```

Edit : To complete your interface requirements, you can add a function template that deduces `T` :

```
template<class T> inline stateid_t GetStateID(T&&) {
    return GetStateID<T>(); 
}
```

Comment: for c++11, I need to do `typeid(typename std::remove_reference<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::type)

Comment: also the `remove_reference` part appears unnecessary: "If applied to a reference type (lvalue), the type_info returned identifies the referenced type. Any const or volatile qualified type is identified as its unqualified equivalent." (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/type_info/)

Comment: @thegreatemu Seems you're right about `std::remove_reference`. I've updated my answer accordingly.